# #subgroups=#subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Why the the number of subgroups with order $p^k$ of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^n$  is equal to the number of $k$ dimensional subspaces of the vector space $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^n$?

Comment: Because those two things are the same in this context.

Answer (score 3):

The group operation of the group $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^n$ is exactly the addition in the vector space $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^n$.  The condition that something be a subspace of the vector space $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^n$ is exactly the condition that it be a subgroup of the group $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^n$ plus be closed under multiplication by elements of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.  But you can check that this additional condition is automatic because every element of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ is an integer and multiplication by it can be thought of as repeated addition.